# Sum of nth powers of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers

Is a closed form for
$$\sum_{i=1}^n{F_i^k}$$
(where $F_i$ is the $i^{th}$ Fibonacci number and $k$ is constant) known?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Combinatorial_identities), we have the following:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n F_i=F_{n+2}-1$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^n F_i^2=F_nF_{n+1}$$

For sum of higher powers of Fibonacci numbers, look at [this helpful blog post](https://dmishin.blogspot.com/2013/07/sums-of-powers-of-fibonacci-numbers.html).

---

One possible inuition behind these formulas is [Binet's formula](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Binet%27s_Formula):
$$F_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^n-\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n\right)$$
Then, for any given constant $k$, we can use binomial expansion to get a bunch of terms that have the form $a\cdot b^n$ and we can find the sum of $\sum_{i=1}^n a\cdot b^i$ using the sum of geometric series formula. I'll apply this to the $k=1$ case:
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^i-\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^i\right)$$
Bring the $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$ out of the sumation:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\sum_{i=1}^n \left(\phi^i-\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^i\right)$$
Distribute the summation over the terms:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\phi^i-\sum_{i=1}^n\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^i\right)$$
Use geometric series formula:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi\frac{\phi^n-1}{\phi-1}-\frac{1}{\phi}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n-1}{\frac{1}{\phi}+1}\right)$$
Use identities about $\phi$:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi\frac{\phi^n-1}{\frac{1}{\phi}}-\frac{1}{\phi}\frac{\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^n-1}{\phi}\right)$$
Simplify:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n+2}-\phi^2-\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^{n+2}+\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^2\right)$$
Note that $\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^2-\phi^2=-\sqrt 5$:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n+2}-\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^{n+2}-\sqrt 5\right)$$
Partially distribute the $\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}$:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\left(\phi^{n+2}-\left(-\frac{1}{\phi}\right)^{n+2}\right)-\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}\cdot \sqrt 5$$
Use Binet's Formula and simplify:
$$F_{n+2}-1$$
As you can see, this method is very cumbersome, so it's probably impractical for very high powers.

Comment: @vadim123 Oh...Did not realize exponent. Sorry! I've added a link to sum of powers of Fibonacci numbers above.

Comment: Since $F_n=(a^n-b^n)/\sqrt 5 , $  where $a=(1+\sqrt 5)/2$ and $b=(1-\sqrt 5)/2=-1/a, $  individual cases with small $k$  (like $k=1$ or $2$) can be evaluated with the binomial theorem and the summing of geometric series. But I haven't looked into it .

Comment: @user254665 Yes, that is in my answer.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Wow. How do you know so much still in high school ? Did you participate in some Olympiads or have mathematician parents or something ? I checked out your YouTube channel too, by the way.

Comment: @user230452 Mostly, I've learned a lot of calculus, abstract algebra, and linear algebra online. I've also learned a lot from this forum and looking at a lot of the Q&A. I also know a lot about algorithms from competition programming like [USACO](http://www.usaco.org/). Also, thanks for checking out my YouTube channel! I think practicing problems there has also helped me a lot.

Comment: @NobleMushtak Hmm ... So, there's a website called Library Genesis which allows you to get free books. You could try it out.

Comment: @user230452 Thank you for the suggestion! However, unfortunately, this is not legal in my country, the U.S., since [a New York district court said it violated copyright law](http://www.nature.com/news/pirate-research-paper-sites-play-hide-and-seek-with-publishers-1.18876).

Comment: @NobleMushtak Oh ! But, it's allowed in mine. Anyway let me know if you need any help with something anytime. Not that I am qualified to help you :P but sometimes someone just older can come in handy.

Comment: @user230452 Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, I'm in high school too :) USACO is pretty cool. Also, you can always use Tor or a VPN... I mean I use scihub all the time, I wouldn't be able to do anything if I couldn't. It might not be legal but I think we can agree it's ethical, especially for people our age.

Comment: @RenéG SciHub is for research articles, right ? Are you able to understand research papers already ?

Comment: @user230452 Not in math :) but for CS like machine learning stuff and whatnot.

Comment: @RenéG Wow. That's pretty cool. Thanks to this thread, I got to know there's an Olympiad for Computer Science too. I thought it was only there for Physics and Math. I'm pretty embarrassed to admit that. By the way, what's a VPN ? And, if you ever need help regarding choosing what books to study to understand a concept or some kind of help like that, you could always contact me too :). I like helping out people.

Comment: A VPN allows you to access the internet in a way that makes it impossible for observers to see what you're doing. So if you're worried about something being illegal you can proxy through a VPN and no one can see what you're doing. But obviously for things like scihub or whatever it's unnecessary, nobody cares anyway.

Answer (score 2):

Consider a generalized Fibonacci sequence $\{U_n\}$ with $U_n=U_n(p,q)$ defined as $U_0=0$, $U_1=1$, and $U_{n+2}=-qU_n+pU_{n+1}$ for all $n\geq0$. It is prove that

$$\sum_{i=1}^nU_i^m=\frac{1}{\sum_{i=1}^m{m\atopwithdelims\{\}i}}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nU_{im-\binom{m+1}{2}}+\sum_{i=1}^m{m\atopwithdelims\{\}i}\sum_{j=1}^i(U_{n-i+j}^m-U_{j-i}^m)\right),$$
in which 
$${m\atopwithdelims\{\}i}=\left(\prod_{\underset{j=1}{j\neq i}}^mU_{j-i}\right)^{-1}.$$
Also, note that in the above formula
$$\sum_{x=1}^nU_{ax+b}=\frac{q^aU_{na+b}-U_{(n+1)a+b}-q^aU_{b-a}+U_b}{1+q^a-V_a}-U_b$$
for all integers $a,b$. See [here](http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/j39/j39.pdf).