# Combinatorial interpretation for sum of powers (specially power=$3$) of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: combinatorics, summation, closed-form, fibonacci-numbers, tiling

Consider the following sum:

$$\sum_{k=0}^{n}F_k^2=F_nF_{n+1}$$

Where $F_n$ is the nth [Fibonacci number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number).

Using a little of algebra it's easy to show that the sum telescopes to $F_nF_{n+1}$.

Now define

> $$G(F,r):=\sum_{k=0}^{n}F_k^r$$
>   Where $r$ is a natural number.

Still using binomial theorem it's possible to find a formula for $G(F,r)$, although the process of calculating would be cumbersome, the first sum can be viewed as a counting problem which has been done [here](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07468342.2018.1424425?journalCode=ucmj20).

---

Let's compute $G(F,3)$ by hand:

The first 11 Fibonacci terms are : $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34,55$

$$0^3=0$$
$$0^3+1^3=1$$
$$0^3+1^3+1^3=2$$
$$0^3+1^3+1^3+2^3=10$$
$$0^3+1^3+1^3+2^3+3^3=37$$
$$0^3+1^3+1^3+2^3+3^3+5^3=162$$
$$0^3+1^3+1^3+2^3+3^3+5^3+8^3=674$$

I cannot see any pattern or at least the pattern is not obvious.

---

If we denote $f_n$ to be the number of ways to tile a board of length $n$ with squares of size $1×1$ and dominoes of size $1×2$ then it's known that $f_n=F_{n+1}$.

Since I don't know what is the RHS of $G(F,3)$ and since I cannot see any pattern , so I'm not able to using tiles to derive a formula.

My questions are :

- Is there any closed formula for $G(F,r)$?
- What would be the combinatorial interpretation for $G(F,3)$

Comment: Related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1844347/sum-of-nth-powers-of-fibonacci-numbers

Comment: @NikoWielopolski, I've already looked at that, but it seems that a closed formula is not known based on the classic Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773958/proof-of-1313233353-cdots-f-n3-fracf-nf-n12-1n1f-n-1?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://oeis.org/A005968